# Write a shell script to print a diamond figure

Tags: bash, shell

This is homework, didn't mean to trick anybody, but I didn't specify that in my original post.

Write a shell script to print the following figure (Do not hardcode).

http://cl.ly/1K0C1b2x3W2N3o3m1Y2y

Comment: What have you tried.  This is clearly homework; we will help you fix your code, but we won't provide you with the answer. How do you know how many lines to print in the diamond?

Comment: do not hardcode and do not ask question without attempting first. Sincerely, your professor

Comment: I really not sure where to start thats why I'm asking for help, I dont know how to do it without manually echoing stars for 11 lines. I dont just want the answer I want some assistance to find it

Comment: I've been racking my brain for an hour on this, and it's only a small part of an assignment that seems to be going well minus this one nagging bit. but I'll try something.

Comment: Take a look at the `for` loop and something like the `seq` command, but you should at least post the code that you have.

Comment: ok I dont know why using a for loop to iterate the number of '*' printed with a max of six, didn't cross my mind. I kind feel stupid for not thinking of that.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1541552/78845

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the one hand, I don't like to just give out an answer.  On the other hand, I think I've made this sufficiently convoluted that, perhaps, there is some educational value in trying to figure out how it works.  Good luck!

```
#!/bin/sh 

while i=$( expr ${i-0} ${op-+} 1 ); do
    j=$i
    t=$( expr 2 \* $i - 1 )
    printf %$( expr \( $( expr 2 \* ${1-6} - 1 ) - $t \) / 2 )s
    while test $(( j-- )) -gt 0; do printf '* '; done
    echo
    test $i = ${1-6} && op=-
done
```

And here's a nice variant:

```
#!/bin/sh

while i=$( expr ${i-0} ${op-+} 1 ); do
    printf %$( expr $(( 2 * $(( ${1-6} - $i )) )) / 2 )s
    printf \*%$(( $i - 1 ))s | sed 's/ / */g'
    test $i = ${1-6} && op=-
done
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll get started on trying to understand it all!

Comment: Thank you, I also figured out how to make it interactive based off of this as well!

Comment: It's fun unravelling it (+1), but to make the diamond fully left justified (as in the pic), the first *printf* needs to end with `\) / 2)s" ''`

Comment: @peter Unfortunately, printf "%0s" ' ' will print one space, so the +1 is needed to align the middle row properly.  You could trim the space off by piping the loop to sed.

Comment: That is true if the initial string is a space.. An initial value of null `''` does the trick though (as in my example... (it does look a bit like a space a space in there, but it isn't ;)